# VS Code Python debug console incomplete

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

Running python scripts in debugger fails to output `sys.stderr`. When my script crashes in the terminal I see the full stack trace while when it crashes while debugging it just finishes without any output.

`RedirectOutput` is supposed to do that,

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

yet it fails.
I am running the `debugOptions` as below in my configuration

```
"debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
```

Running python 2.7 by the way

Comment: even though I could resolve this, the combination or distinction between debug console and terminal is not solved well in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. It's a mix of settings.

Now it pipes all output into the terminal instead of the `debug_console` and displays every channel stdout & stderr

```
"debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "stopOnEntry": false
```